# Is there any way to check the status of connection to IBM WorkLight Server?

Tags: ios, swift, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm working on a native iOS app that is using `IBM Worklight` server adapters.

Is there any function or any further way that let me able to know if I'm currently connected to the server (so my session is open and I can invoke my procedure immediately) or not then I need to establish new connection via `WLClient().wlConnectWithDelegate(self)` ?

Comment: I think this is not a matter of upvoting , we're working on critical point and all of our work is pending on this answer , that's why

Comment: IBM has an official support channel where you should ask for help on mission critical subjects (opening a PMR). Stack Overflow is a community of individuals, some are IBMers, most are not. Upvoting this question will not help you to get help faster (and is also not the intended use of upvoting a question or an answer). In any case, I have answered your question.

Comment: Please don't insult or use such words , I've asked lot's of my colleagues about this point and they advised to put this questions as representative on behalf of all of them that's why they put up-vote immediately after I published the questions because we may revise our APP structure if we found a function or any other way to check the connection

Comment: I agree that you should ask the question, it's a good and valid question! I am only not agreeing with this upvoting method, which is not helpful. Upvoting a question will not get you help faster, that is all.

Comment: There is no such API available...

Comment: thanks for cooperation Mr.Idan

Answer (score 1):

There is no such API provided by the Worklight framework.

The idea behind the connect API is to establish a session between the client and server, negating a possible occurrence of a race condition (for example two adapter requests to the server, each getting its own session, potentially causing trouble). This, in addition to delivering data on headers that is not available in an adapter request compared to connect request.

I think that instead of making a connect request before invocation you can do it in an early stage in the app's lifecycle, as well as whenever the app returns to the foreground, to ensure that a session was established. This, coupled together with an appropriate session timeout set in worklight.properties on the server-side.

More here: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-0/hello-world/connecting-to-the-mobilefirst-server/

Comment: Mr.Idan thanks for answer however I need to check the connection because my App may call the server from different modules so I need to know the status of connection before deciding either to open a new connection or proceeding with invocation. Thanks again

Comment: Unfortunately there is no available method to check the status of the connection... the only way is to workaround it by trying to connect the server at key locations such as the ones mentioned.